# Explicit powers of 2 in biginteger operations

Tags: c#, vb.net, biginteger, integer-division, bit-shift

I have a piece of code which goes like (vb.net or c# "language" is immaterial):

```
 Dim Counter As BigInteger = 0
 Serial = BigInteger.DivRem(Serial, 4, Counter)
 CountersList.Add(CInt(Counter))
```

Since I was making many of those division by 4, with very large positive integers (several hundred digits) and after receiving a few "out of memory exceptions", I went to give another reading to the documentation.

In the shift operator [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.op_leftshift.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) I can read:
"Languages that do not support custom operators can perform a bitwise left-shift operation by multiplying 
value by BigInteger.Pow(2, shift)."

So I though that the above code could, perhaps, improve this way (making explicit i am dividing by a power of 2):

```
Dim Counter As BigInteger = 0
Serial = BigInteger.DivRem(Serial, BigInteger.Pow(2, 2), Counter)
CountersList.Add(CInt(Counter))
```

My question.

- In general, is there any advantage to explicitly use the BigInteger.Pow(), so that perhaps (?) the compiler knows it can perform shifts, instead of multiplication/division?
- In my specific case, where I need to make the division by 4, and get both the result and the remainder, what is the best way to go ?

Comment: IIRC, `Pow` works different for negative numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In general, is there any advantage to explicitly use the BigInteger.Pow(), so that perhaps (?) the compiler knows it can perform shifts, instead of multiplication/division?

There is no support for `BigInteger` in CIL (the intermediate language, i.e. assembly code, behind .NET's languages), so no, the compiler cannot optimize it. (Unless it had some very specific support for `BigInteger` in such a way to understand it can replace a 'divide by 4' by 'shift right by two bits' etc.)

> In my specific case, where I need to make the division by 4, and get both the result and the remainder, what is the best way to go ?

You can use a sequence of `And` to get the remainder and `>>` to perform the division, e.g.:

```
Dim Remainder as BigInteger = Serial And New BigInteger(3)
Serial = Serial >> 2
```

(Note: Sorry for possible syntax errors, VB is not my language.)

However, I don't think the source of `OutOfMemoryException` are these trivial operations. Inspect the expection's stack trace to know where it's happening at the first place.

Comment: Thank you Ondrej, that is very interesting. Could you help me understanding your way to get the remainder ? Is that a way to "grab" two of the bits before the shift?

Comment: In binary the remainders can be 00, 01, 10, and 11 for a division by four.  Three is 11 in binary so the AND gets the remainder.  If you are keeping the quotient and remainder in memory, and doing enough of them, you may still have out of memory problems.

Comment: @dbasnett Thank you. I imagine it's because it's little endian format that we use 11 for the first 2 bits.  I note however that the shifting is noted at language level "to the right" anyway, even if the bits in the biginteger get actually shifted to left (I think).

Comment: Endianness is purely matter of implementation in the CPU. It has nothing to do with bitwise ops as long as you interpret a given set of bytes as a single integer number.

Comment: @Ondrej Yep, you are right. Thank you for the instructive answer :-)